# FormData of file array not working in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, multipartform-data, multer, form-data

I'm trying to upload video file from expo react-native to express backend.
I'm using multer middleware for express.
I tested backend with react frontend.
this is react front-end code

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

  const saveImage = (e) => {
    setImages((prev) => [...prev, e.target.files[0]]);
  };

  const saveVideos = (e) => {
    setVideos((prev) => [...prev, e.target.files[0]]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    videos.forEach((file, index) => {
      formData.append(`videos`, file);
      console.log(formData.getAll("videos"));
    });

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8082/api/product/savetest", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input onChange={saveVideos} name="videos" type="file" />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>save</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

it works well.

I implemented this logic in react native

```js
 let data = new FormData();
      data.append("title", formData.title);
      data.append("price", formData.price);
      data.append("size", formData.size);
      data.append("cat_id", formData.category);
      data.append("description", formData.description);

      formData?.videos?.map((video, index)=>{
        data.append("videos", {
          uri: video.uri,
          type: 'video/*',
          name: `video_${index}.mp4`,
        })
      })
      const res = await axios.post(baseUrl + "/api/product/save", data, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "x-access-token": accessToken,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
```

but not working...

I'm not sure what is wrong..
Maybe React and React-Native is different in use case of formdata?
If someone have experience in this, please help me.

this is backend

```js
import multer from "multer";

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post("/api/product/save", [authJwt.verifyToken, upload.array("videos")], saveProduct);
async function saveProduct(req, res) {
  //Form Valdiation
  console.log(req.body)
  const { errors, isValid } = ValidateProductInput(req.body);
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  const { images, title, price, description, cat_id, size } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);

  console.log("video----", req.files);

  let imageUrls;
  if (images?.length) {
    imageUrls = await Promise.all([
      ...images?.map((image, key) => {
        return uploadProductImgToFirebase(image, Date.now() + title + key);
      }),
    ]);
  }

  let videoUrls;
  if (req.files?.length) {
    videoUrls = await Promise.all([
      ...req.files?.map((video, key) => {
        return uploadProductVideoToFirebase(video, Date.now() + title + key);
      }),
    ]);
  }

  console.log(imageUrls);
  console.log(videoUrls);
  new Product({
    user_id: req.id,
    images: imageUrls,
    videos: videoUrls,
    title: title,
    price: price,
    description: description,
    cat_id: cat_id,
    size: size,
  })
    .save()
    .then((product) => {
      return res.json({
        success: true,
        message: "Your product has been added.",
        data: product,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

req.files need to look like this

```js
[
{
originalname: "xxxxx",
mimetype: "video/mp4",
....
}
]
```